# Middle of あなたがいるから: singulars or plurals?

Tags: translation, song-lyrics, song

[Part 1](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/100023/help-understanding-the-beginning-of-the-song-%e3%81%82%e3%81%aa%e3%81%9f%e3%81%8c%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89)    Part 2    [Part 3](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/100026/help-understanding-the-third-section-of-%e3%81%82%e3%81%aa%e3%81%9f%e3%81%8c%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89)    [Part 4](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/100027/%e3%81%82%e3%81%aa%e3%81%9f%e3%81%8c%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89-will-to-kneel-or-kneeling-stone-and-other-things-about-those-two)

This is part two of what was mostly a cross-post of [this Quora post](https://mickgorroonyoutubeartisticsongtranslations.quora.com/Today-we-have-a-Japanese-song-which-I-met-ages-ago-in-late-2011-and-soon-translated-to-Italian-Chinese-English-and).

The song is [this one](https://lyricstranslate.com/en/detektiv-conan-ost-anata-ga-iru-kara-lyrics.html), and the lyrics go:

もしもこの世に汚れがなければ
姿を変えずに愛し合えたのに
どうして時は衆を分つの
ねえそばにいて今だけ

あなたがいるから私は強くなる
誓いの指輪きらきらきれいね
You will realize 小さな夢も
You are the one 心満たされる

夜のハイウエイバイクを飛ばして
はしゃいだ自由を持て余すくらい
この目で見て触れて分かる
確かなものがあったね

あの日の二人にすべて戻らせるなら
ひざまづく意志になるまでに祈るよ
We can still be free 百まで数えて
Never wanna stop 心解き放つ

あなたがいるから私は強くなる
誓いの指輪きらきらきれいね
You will realize 小さな夢も
You are the one いつか叶えられる

In transliteration:

Moshi mo kono yo ni kegare ga nakereba
Sugata wo kaezu ni aishiaeta noni
Doushite toki wa shū wo wakatsu no?
Nee, soba ni ite ima dake

Anata ga iru kara watashi wa tsuyoku naru
Chikai no yubiwa kirakira kirei ne
You will relize chiisa na yume mo
You are the one kokoro mitasareru

Yoru no haiuei baiku o tobashite
Hashaida jiyuu o moteamasu kurai
Kono me de mite furete wakaru
Tashika na mono ga atta ne

Ano hi no futari ni subete modoserunara
Hizamazuki ishi ni naru made inoru you
We can still be free hyaku made kazoete
Never wanna stop kokoro tokihanatsu

Anata ga iru kara watashi wa tsuyoku naru
Chikai no yubiwa kirakira kirei ne
You will realize chiisa na yume mo
You are the one itsuka kannaerareru

And this is the translation attempt [I posted to lyricstranslate](https://lyricstranslate.com/en/anata-ga-iru-kara-youre-me.html), with one or two edits:

Even if there were no impurity* in this world    LT has "contamination"
So that [we] could've loved each other without having to change our looks…
Why does time separate [simple] people?    "simple" was added here.
Hey, be by [my] side, at least now

Since you're there, I get stronger
The ring of [my] promise is sparkling, beautiful isn't it?
You will realize even [my] small dreams
You are the one, [my] heart is satisfied

On the highway at night riding a motorbike
Till [I] don't know what to do with the freedom of making merry
[I'll] see with these eyes and touch, and understand
That this has been real    [lit. That there has been a real thing [between us]]

If it will let everything return to [how it was] in the days of us two,
[I] will pray till [I] want to fall on [my] knees
We can still be free, count till a hundred
Never wanna stop, I will set my heart loose

Since you're there, I get stronger
The ring of [my] promise is sparkling, beautiful isn't it?
You will realize even [my] small dreams
You are the one, [my] heart is satisfied

I also [asked a question on Quora](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-good-or-bad-is-the-translation-of-the-Japanese-song-%E3%81%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8C%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89-that-I-have-posted-to-lyricstranslate-as-MickG-link-in-question-comments) about this attempt.

The second question is a matter of singular and plural in the following two lines:

誓いの指輪きらきらきれいね
You will realize 小さな夢も

Japanese doesn’t mark number, so it could be “the ring of the promise”, “the rings of the promise”, “the ring of the promises”, “the rings of the promises”, and also “even the small dream” or “even the small dreams”. I don’t recall “no” marking material, so “the ring of vows” seems wrong. I was taking this to mean an engagement ring, so “the ring of the [=our] promise”, and then what small dream are we talking about? I’d go with plural, so “even the smallest dreams I have”. Is there any reason to do otherwise?

Comment: Your question deals with two lines, so I don't see why the entire set of lyrics and their translation need to be given...

Comment: The last two lines have 小さな夢もいつか叶えられる, though you seem to have missed it in your translation. This makes more sense as a sentence than 小さな夢も心満たされる. There, 小さな夢 would be most probably understood as a dream in general, rather than someone’s specific dream. Not sure about 小さな夢も心満たされる. The subject and the predicate don’t seem to be matching.

Comment: @aguijonazo You're right. That's animelyrics' fault, I didn't realise they'd missed it. I think in the first version of those lines it's supposed to be "You will realise chiisana yume mo", and then "You are the one [by whom] kokoro mitasareru", and the second version still has the double duty of "chiisana yume mo". That's why I'd read those as the singer's dreams rather than a, singular, generic dream.

Comment: I think few people would try to make sense out of the English portions and the Japanese portions combined as though they make up one sentence. Many would take the English portions to be inserted in between a Japanese sentence, just to sound cool or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this 誓いの指輪 is a wedding ring, it's typically singular, but it could be a pair of rings to symbolize their love. We never know. All you can do is imagine the situation as concretely as possible and make the most likely decision.

> what small dream are we talking about?

I don't know what it is exactly, but I don't see any reason to assume they're trying to realize many dreams simultaneously.

Comment: If they're in love, wouldn't they be trying to realise all of each other's dreams?

Comment: @MickG Judging from the entire lyrics, the two were truly in love in the past, but they are separated now. This is a song about missing a lover who has gone somewhere for some reason (you should be able to tell this just by looking at the first verse). I think she's still hoping *his* dream will come true some day. So I take this 夢 as "your dream", not "our dream" nor "my dream".