# Help understanding the third section of あなたがいるから

Tags: translation, song-lyrics, song

[Part 1](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/100023/help-understanding-the-beginning-of-the-song-%e3%81%82%e3%81%aa%e3%81%9f%e3%81%8c%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89)    [Part 2](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/100025/middle-of-%e3%81%82%e3%81%aa%e3%81%9f%e3%81%8c%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89-singulars-or-plurals)    Part 3    [Part 4](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/100027/%e3%81%82%e3%81%aa%e3%81%9f%e3%81%8c%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89-will-to-kneel-or-kneeling-stone-and-other-things-about-those-two)

This is part three of what was mostly a cross-post of [this Quora post](https://mickgorroonyoutubeartisticsongtranslations.quora.com/Today-we-have-a-Japanese-song-which-I-met-ages-ago-in-late-2011-and-soon-translated-to-Italian-Chinese-English-and).

The song is [this one](https://lyricstranslate.com/en/detektiv-conan-ost-anata-ga-iru-kara-lyrics.html), and the lyrics go:

もしもこの世に汚れがなければ
姿を変えずに愛し合えたのに
どうして時は衆を分つの
ねえそばにいて今だけ

あなたがいるから私は強くなる
誓いの指輪きらきらきれいね
You will realize 小さな夢も
You are the one 心満たされる

夜のハイウエイバイクを飛ばして
はしゃいだ自由を持て余すくらい
この目で見て触れて分かる
確かなものがあったね

あの日の二人にすべて戻らせるなら
ひざまづく意志になるまでに祈るよ
We can still be free 百まで数えて
Never wanna stop 心解き放つ

あなたがいるから私は強くなる
誓いの指輪きらきらきれいね
You will realize 小さな夢も
You are the one いつか叶えられる

In transliteration:

Moshi mo kono yo ni kegare ga nakereba
Sugata wo kaezu ni aishiaeta noni
Doushite toki wa shū wo wakatsu no?
Nee, soba ni ite ima dake

Anata ga iru kara watashi wa tsuyoku naru
Chikai no yubiwa kirakira kirei ne
You will relize chiisa na yume mo
You are the one kokoro mitasareru

Yoru no haiuei baiku o tobashite
Hashaida jiyuu o moteamasu kurai
Kono me de mite furete wakaru
Tashika na mono ga atta ne

Ano hi no futari ni subete modoserunara
Hizamazuki ishi ni naru made inoru you
We can still be free hyaku made kazoete
Never wanna stop kokoro tokihanatsu

Anata ga iru kara watashi wa tsuyoku naru
Chikai no yubiwa kirakira kirei ne
You will realize chiisa na yume mo
You are the one itsuka kannaerareru

And this is the translation attempt [I posted to lyricstranslate](https://lyricstranslate.com/en/anata-ga-iru-kara-youre-me.html), with one or two edits:

Even if there were no impurity* in this world    LT has "contamination"
So that [we] could've loved each other without having to change our looks…
Why does time separate [simple] people?    "simple" was added here.
Hey, be by [my] side, at least now

Since you're there, I get stronger
The ring of [my] promise is sparkling, beautiful isn't it?
You will realize even [my] small dreams
You are the one, [my] heart is satisfied

On the highway at night riding a motorbike
Till [I] don't know what to do with the freedom of making merry
[I'll] see with these eyes and touch, and understand
That this has been real    [lit. That there has been a real thing [between us]]

If it will let everything return to [how it was] in the days of us two,
[I] will pray till [I] want to fall on [my] knees
We can still be free, count till a hundred
Never wanna stop, I will set my heart loose

Since you're there, I get stronger
The ring of [my] promise is sparkling, beautiful isn't it?
You will realize even [my] small dreams
You are the one, [my] heart is satisfied

I also [asked a question on Quora](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-good-or-bad-is-the-translation-of-the-Japanese-song-%E3%81%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8C%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89-that-I-have-posted-to-lyricstranslate-as-MickG-link-in-question-comments) about this attempt.

Since they are about the same section, just the two halves of it, I assume I can ask questions 3 and 4 together? The section is:

夜のハイウエイバイクを飛ばして
はしゃいだ自由を持て余すくらい
この目で見て触れて分かる
確かなものがあったね

Animelyrics:

On the highway at night riding the bike
Till the freedom to enjoy becomes annoying
I saw with these eyes, touch and you'll see
There are things that are real

**First half**

First line is literally “Highway of the night, riding a “baiku””. So animelyrics is pretty correct… except “baiku” is not bike, but motorbike, AFAICT. And I mean, a bike on the highway? What was the translator smoking?

Line 2, however, is the problem. Word by word:

- Hashaida: frolicked, made merry; dried out?
- jiyū wo: freedom (object);
- motehanasu: not know what to do with;
- kurai: «① approximately ● about ● around ● or so ② to (about) the extent that ● (almost) enough that ● so ... that ... ● at least ③ as ... as ... ● like ＊», or maybe « ① dark ● gloomy ② dark (in colour) ● dull ③ depressed ● dispirited ④ sorrowful ● bitter (as in a dark past) ⑤ unclear ● unfamiliar ● unknown ＊», or even «① throne ● crown ● (nobleman's) seat ② government position ● court rank ③ social standing ● rank ● class ● echelon ● rung ④ grade (of quality, etc.) ● level ● tier ● rank ⑤ digit (e.g. the tens, the hundreds, etc.) ● place ⑥ degree ● extent ● amount ＊».

So I guess something like «I’m riding my m-b on the highway at night / Enough that I don’t know what to do with the freedom with which I’ve been frolicking», or less literally «I drive my m-b on the highway at night / Until I no longer know what to do with my freedom of making merry». Or maybe I should take that as a “dried-out freedom”, as in, he’s probably alone on the highway, hence “free” in some sense, but that freedom is full of sadness and loneliness (“dried out”), and eventually he doesn’t want it anymore?

**Second half**

Glaring problem in the animelyrics translation: atta is past, so there must be a “there were / have been” somewhere in that line, not a “there are”. Word by word:

- Kono me de: with these (=my) eyes (here the singular wouldn’t really
  fit IMO);
- mite: looking;
- furete: touching;
- wakaru: understand;
- tashikana: real, reliable;
- mono ga: thing(s) or person/people (subject);
- atta: there were, used for things, as ita is used for people;
- ne: question tag.

Since a sequence of -te forms ending in a non-past or past form is the equivalent of «I do/did X and do/did Y and do/did Z», this could either be «Seeing with these eyes and touching, [] (will) understand / That there has/have been (a) real thing(s)» or «[] will see with these eyes and touch and understand / […]». Either way, animelyrics is dead wrong in separating the -te sequence, and especially wrong in translating mite as “saw” when it’s basically an -ing form. Since “these eyes” are definitely “my eyes”, that whole line probably has subject “I”, so the “[]” in my translations above can be replaced by “I”.

The last line, however, is more to-be-interpreted. To me, the “mono” should be the feeling/relationship between the singer and the addressee, so «There was a real thing [between us]», or «This has been real», in a less literal version.

So for the first half, we have two translation:

On the highway at night riding a motorbike
Till [I] don't know what to do with the freedom of making merry

Or:

On the highway at night riding a motorbike
Till [I] don't know what to do with [my] dried-up freedom

Where "dried-up freedom" would mean "withered", so no longer enjoyable, ruined by being all alone.

For the second half, we also have two options, though the situation is more of a "could you comment on my remarks":

[I'll] see with these eyes and touch, and understand
That this has been real    [lit. That there has been a real thing [between us]]

Or:

Seeing with these eyes and touching, [I] will understand
That this has been real    [lit. That there has been a real thing [between us]]

Comment: "So animelyrics is pretty correct… except “baiku” is not bike, but motorbike, AFAICT. And I mean, a bike on the highway? What was the translator smoking?" This is *not a Japanese translation issue*, but an English usage one. Depending on dialect and culture, it is entirely possible for native English speakers to say "bike" and mean a motorcycle. The Japanese loanword comes from "bike" exactly because of that sort of slang usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

###### First half

That はしゃいだ is not a relative clause modifying 自由. Here is the same sentence in a "prosaic" word order:

> 夜のハイウェイ[を](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3243/5010)、自由を持て余す[くらい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/29457/5010)、バイクを飛ばしてはしゃいだ。
>
> On the night highway, we sped the motorcycle and frolicked, to the point where we didn't know how to spend our freedom.

自由を持て余す means having too much freedom to make use of. For example, an unemployed person might say this. The sentence is saying that speeding the motorcycle made them feel so excited that they almost felt they had infinite freedom. And forget "dried out"; nothing in the lyrics says such a thing.

Don't ignore the past tense (はしゃい**だ**). This scene is her past memory. Translating this as "I'm driving" means you have missed the most crucial theme of this song.

###### Second half

> この目で見て触れて分かる確かなものがあったね。
>
> There was a real something which I could feel/understand by seeing with my eyes and touching(, you know?)

Those te-forms [express means](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/75172/5010). This もの is basically just "thing" or "something", but it vaguely refers to everything in this beautiful and real memory of hers. He was real, and she could actually see him, hear him, touch him, and feel him. She is remembering it vividly.

Comment: "Dried out" was because of sense 2 [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%AF%E3%81%97%E3%82%83%E3%81%90), but since that's not a relative clause that's a moot point.<br>
<br>
So the sum-up is: 1. Put a comma after "hashaida", 2. "wakaru" is a relative clause (and the linebreak somewhat obscures that).<br>
<br>
And that Kazuhito Minato is not to be trusted :).

Comment: @MickG Oh, yes, my monolingual dictionary also lists "dry out"! But it's a completely obsolete meaning, and I didn't know it. わかる is closer to "understandable" here.